# tokens in visual studio: HACK, TODO... any other?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, token

what tokens do you find useful in visual studio?
(*visual studio 2010* → **environment** → **task list** → tokens)

currently i have only:

- **HACK** - *low*
- **REVIEW - high**
- **TODO** - normal
- **WTF - high**

(only these - deleted some default ones)

**are you using any others?**

**are you covering any other important thing with comment tokens?**

any best practices? thnx

Comment: Should probably be community wiki.

Comment: for who lands here looking for the task list tokens in visual studio, note that the menu commands are visual studio → tools → options → environment → task list → tokens

Comment: In the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list?view=vs-2022), there are indicated s follows 
Custom tokens
By default, Visual Studio includes the following tokens: 
1) HACK 
2) TODO
3) UNDONE
4) UnresolvedMergeConflict. 

They are not case-sensitive. You can also create your own custom tokens.

Comment: hehe WTF:  that's so funny

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's the ones I use:

- **TODO**: the functionality is not yet implemented
- **FIXME**: the code should be modified/refactored to achieve some goal (higher maintainability, better performance, and so on)
- **BUG**: the code has a known bug

Comment: i like fixme and bug :) i use hack for fixme. will add bug!

Comment: I use the same :) -- I do subcatagories for my FIXME's, i.e.: FIXME - Performance.

Comment: Yup. And TODO - TRANSLATE. We use Mantis#123 to refer to our bugtracking system and the corresponding number.

Answer (score 30):

I've done a combination of most of the above tokens.

```
 RED: code that simply does not work / compile
 // Error - This code is throwing a specific reproducible error.
 // Broken - This code is broken and will not run.
 // WTF - WHAT THE FRIG.

 ORANGE: code that works but is not right
 // Hack - This code has intentionally been hacked in order to work. Should not go into production.
 // FixMe - This code works but could be better. Needs better abstraction, maintainability, performance, etc.
 // Bug - This code works and was expected to be right but a bug has been found. (usually flagged post production)
 // Review - This code is probably right but should be reviewed for piece of mind.
 // Smells - Same as FixMe

 BLUE: code that works but either needs more features or more explaining
 // Todo - Functionality is not yet implemented
 // Note - Better explain what's going on. This is gives a higher profile to standard comments, and allows notes to be found in the to-do pane.
```

Comment: I don't necessarily use ALL of these, but depending on my mood that day, I'll get the highlights one way or another.

Comment: That's kind of a cool thing if all employees in your company have the same tokens highlighted. If the don't it just makes comments harder to  understand in some cases.

Comment: How is _functionality not yet implemented_ code that works?

Comment: piece of mind? *eg*

Answer (score 9):

I like the Token REMOVE, indicating that it's only in for testing, and should not be included in the final release

Comment: This is an extremely bad practice. If the code is for testing, then use conditional compilation with preprocessor directives.

Comment: @AMissico but `// REMOVE` is easier

Answer (score 7):

Another built-in is NOTE.

Comment: yeah, didn't like it since isn't any comment a NOTE somehow?

Comment: Agreed, but I try not to use comments at all except for NOTE. If I have anything else, it goes into the tracking system. In my case JIRA.

Comment: ah, i see, i use comments a bit more :P

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the old green ink :)

Comment: Note: not only changes the default comment color, but it also can give profile to the note within the todo pane.

Comment: NOTE its usefull when you want to force someone to read your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Vim automatically highlights `XXX`, which happens to be my token of choice for the ease of typing it.

[Sun's (old) Java coding conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc9.html) have this to say:

> Use `XXX` in a comment to flag something that is bogus but works. Use `FIXME` to flag something that is bogus and broken.

Comment: nice tip about vim. didn't know that.