# Visual Studio 2010 - Task List. What is the UNDONE token used for?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide, annotations

I know these are customisable, but I'm intrigued as to what the last one indicates.

- TODO
- HACK
- UNDONE

Has anyone ever used this? If so, what for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944360/tokens-in-visual-studio-hack-todo-any-other

Comment: Yes, I've seen that thread. Obviously you can add more tokens as you deem fit, but I was interested as to why UNDONE was in the list as a default. It must be in general use somewhere for it to have been included you'd have thought...

Answer (score 5):

It looks to be for incomplete code. As in: I'm not done with this part, so I will remind myself to start here next time.

> Whenever you are typing code and you know that you are about to leave something undone, simply type in a comment that starts with ‘undone’. When you do this, Visual Studio .NET can show all your undone items in the Task List toolwindow.

FROM:
http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip9.asp

Comment: Thanks for your response - that is interesting, however I think it could perhaps be better named e.g. INCOMPLETE

Comment: No disagreement here - I found this S.O. because I wondered what UNDONE could be used for and if I should be using it. +1 on INCOMPLETE, I've thought of adding FINISHTHISDUMMY but that's just me. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Visual Studio's "Code Comments" : What Do They Mean?

10 years later and nobody around the world seems to know or agree on what these "code comments" or "tokens" mean in Visual Studio. So, I am posting this answer to help the **poor traveler** who might stumble into this question, yet again...after googling the internet for hours...

Listed below are the only true "*default code comments*" (tokens) that come with **Visual Studio**. They allow you to type a specially prefixed comment in your code and have them appear under a "*Task List*" window, accessed by going to `View > Task List` in Microsoft's various versions of Visual Studio. My description or interpretation of what each comment represents is not a hard and fast rule, but how most people interpret them. Because the meaning is so muddled, I would use this as a general guide:

```
    // TODO: Use TODO to comment some new code, task, or logic that needs to be added or completed below. This could be any kind of reminder, actually.
    // HACK: Use HACK to comment some code that was a "hack" (i.e. poorly written) or quick fix and likely needs to be rewritten.
    // UNDONE: Use UNDONE to comment some incomplete code that was left unfinished and needs to be completed soon.
```

**I do not know why these *strange terms* were created as they are not intuitive.** The only one in the list I do use is "**TODO**" as it is generic enough to mean *anything*.

Nobody I know leaves a "HACK" in their code, which sounds more like a security alert! "UNDONE" is the same as the other two and tells you nothing about the state of your code. Is that code that needs a few fixes, will not compile, needs polishing, is creating exceptions? Maybe there was a reason the code there needs to "stay undone", or to someone stumbling across the code it now "feels undone" lol.

I consider all these the same as a "warning" or "alert" of some kind - something *bad* in the code that was left behind by someone somewhere that someone somewhere might want to investigate (which is generally not how most quality developers code in modern programming today!)

**CUSTOM CODE COMMENTS**

You can create better code comments in VS that you name yourself. These have to be manually added under the Visual Studio menu `Tools > Options > Environment > Task List`.

I generally do not like custom code comments unless your whole team is adamant about using them across all environments. In that one case, you should delete the default ones listed above in your settings and rely on a few custom comments you create in Visual Studio you can rely on and with titles that make logical sense.

These custom token names below make more sense to me as "code comments":

```
// BUG: ...
// TOFIX: ...
// TOADD: ...
// ERROR: ...
// REMOVE: ...
// REWRITE: ...
```

Again, you have to manually enter these in Visual Studio and hope other developers do the same, or they will not appear in the Task List.

Good luck!

Comment: Good ideas, Stokely! I also use HACK with code that was intentionally written in an odd manner such as when prettier-looking/more-intuitive/etc. code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's [Comment (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)#Tags) article claims :

> UNDONE — a reversal or "roll back" of previous code.

However, neither of three source links nearby mention UNDONE. Nor there's any mention in Talk.

This claim was [added to this article at 14 June 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comment_(computer_programming)&diff=prev&oldid=666876216). And didn't contain any proof-link about UNDONE at that time either.

Answer (score 1):

A screenshot that currently appears at Microsoft's [Use the Task List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list?view=vs-2022#the-task-list-window) page contains:

> UNDONE Check-in #42

The purpose of UNDONE still is not obvious to me. Perhaps it means that some code changes did not work so they were rolled back (i.e., "undone").

Answer (score -1):

The UNDONE tag does not seem to be used too much; I personally never used it.

I suppose it would be to let people know that some code has been removed;

```
    // UNDONE: unnecessary code removed...
```

I'm not too sure about its usefulness thought, I would also like to know if anybody uses this.

Comment: This was something I'd considered too. You have some code that has been added as a temporary workaround for some issue or other that has since been removed. My only other thought is that you might use it to tag commented out code to differentiate it from bona fide comments.