# Vim expand default highlighting keyword list in vimrc

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

By default vim highlights tags in comments like TODO, FIXME and XXX, but those three don't usually cover everything, posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452934/what-is-the-meaning-of-xxx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944360/tokens-in-visual-studio-hack-todo-any-other) show that there are many other useful tags and also many useful levels of tags so I tried to implement them. After some research I tried to create new syntax group and added the following to .vimrc:

```
syn keyword myBroken BROKEN ERROR WTF
syn keyword myWarning HACK BUG REVIEW FIXME TODO NOTE

hi def link myBroken Error
hi def link myWarning Todo
```

However this did not work, so I tried to add these to `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/syntax.vim`, that didn't work either, so I then tried to put it in `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` and tried these only in c files, that still didn't work. I checked `runtimepath` and it does contain `$HOME/.vim/after`, so I was confused.

Then I thought maybe keyword is not matched in comments so I tried to replace `syn keyword myBroken BROKEN ERROR WTF` with `syn match myBroken /\v<(ERROR|BROKEN|WTF)/ containedin=.*Comment` but that still doesn't work. Any idea on what I did wrong or how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [`:help mysyntaxfile-add`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-add) it was the correct way how to do it. I do not know why it is not working for you but you can probably go around like this:

```
au BufWinEnter * let w:m1=matchadd('Error', 'BROKEN\|WTF', -1)
au BufWinEnter * let w:m1=matchadd('Todo', 'HACK\|BUG\|REVIEW\|FIXME\|TODO\|NOTE', -1)
```

See [`:help matchadd()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchadd%28%29) for more information.

Comment: Me neither. You can also check if your file was sourced by `:scriptnames`.